# T-SQL Inner Join Optimization between View and Table Value Function

Tags: function, t-sql, join, view

I have a view and table value function, and make inner join between them. There are few millions records from each side that should be joined.

I have read a lot of how to optimize joins (the most common answer is to use indexes, but my view can not be indexed view) but still did not find a way of how join between view and function should be done in a correct way and optimized.

EDIT:

To show that the problem is the inner join indeed - I made "SELECT COUNT(*)" for each query:

1. View - 0 seconds
2. Function - 18 seconds
3. Function inner join View - 42 seconds

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look from the other point of view - do you really need this join on such huge amount of data?
I have the similar issue and this is my situation and solution :

1. There was no needs in all of millions records in my case - just a specific filtered data
2. I've created triggers for insert\update\delete from that huge table to some other - they aimed to track data I need
3. Now I can make fast joins on that specific (let's say - filtered) data

This approach has his own proc and cons; main inconvenience - you should rebuild\review your DB structure: that way maybe not suitable in all cases

Anyway - this is my solution of my particular issue, and it still works fine, I've increased performance at least in 10 times

Comment: @Generally, this is true, but at this particular situation I am using already created database with logic, functions,etc., so I have not got the power or permission to redesign the all system...